# OpenCV - how to count objects in photo?

Tags: c++, opencv

i try to count objects in photo, but can not get the right result.

i try this code
http://opencv-code.com/tutorials/count-and-segment-overlapping-objects-with-watershed-and-distance-transform/

[This is result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcYA5.png)

You can see in the lThe left image has 9 objects,, and after I run the code, I get the right picture of 11 objects.
I introduced MessageBoxW with ncomp, and you can see that ncomp get 11, instead 9.

I searched a lot but could not find another code works brings me the result of 9.

I would like someone to repair this Code shall I use it, or will link to a code that I can use it and get the right result of a number of objects.

This is the code I use:

```
cv::Mat src = cv::imread("c:\\pic\\test.jpg");
if (!src.data)
    return -1;

cv::imshow("src", src);

// Create binary image from source image
cv::Mat bw;
cv::cvtColor(src, bw, CV_BGR2GRAY);
cv::threshold(bw, bw, 40, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
cv::imshow("bw", bw);

// Perform the distance transform algorithm
cv::Mat dist;
cv::distanceTransform(bw, dist, CV_DIST_L2, 3);

// Normalize the distance image for range = {0.0, 1.0}
// so we can visualize and threshold it
cv::normalize(dist, dist, 0, 1., cv::NORM_MINMAX);
cv::imshow("dist", dist);

// Threshold to obtain the peaks 
// This will be the markers for the foreground objects
cv::threshold(dist, dist, .5, 1., CV_THRESH_BINARY);
cv::imshow("dist2", dist);

// Create the CV_8U version of the distance image
// It is needed for cv::findContours()
cv::Mat dist_8u;
dist.convertTo(dist_8u, CV_8U);

// Find total markers
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
cv::findContours(dist_8u, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
int ncomp = contours.size();

// Create the marker image for the watershed algorithm
cv::Mat markers = cv::Mat::zeros(dist.size(), CV_32SC1);

// Draw the foreground markers
for (int i = 0; i < ncomp; i++)
    cv::drawContours(markers, contours, i, cv::Scalar::all(i+1), -1);

// Draw the background marker
cv::circle(markers, cv::Point(5,5), 3, CV_RGB(255,255,255), -1);
cv::imshow("markers", markers*10000);

// Perform the watershed algorithm
cv::watershed(src, markers);

// Generate random colors
std::vector<cv::Vec3b> colors;
for (int i = 0; i < ncomp; i++)
{
    int b = cv::theRNG().uniform(0, 255);
    int g = cv::theRNG().uniform(0, 255);
    int r = cv::theRNG().uniform(0, 255);

    colors.push_back(cv::Vec3b((uchar)b, (uchar)g, (uchar)r));
}

// Create the result image
cv::Mat dst = cv::Mat::zeros(markers.size(), CV_8UC3);

// Fill labeled objects with random colors
for (int i = 0; i < markers.rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < markers.cols; j++)
    {
        int index = markers.at<int>(i,j);
        if (index > 0 && index <= ncomp)
            dst.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j) = colors[index-1];
        else
            dst.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j) = cv::Vec3b(0,0,0);
    }
}

cv::imshow("dst", dst);

wchar_t buffer[256];
wsprintfW(buffer, L"%d", ncomp);
MessageBoxW(nullptr, buffer, buffer, MB_OK);

cv::waitKey(0);
return 0;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Er... I see 11 separate objects in the photo, exactly what the count says.  Did you try playing around with the color threshold values?

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce the code using linux, code::blocks and opencv3.1.0, but I'm getting an nginx 504 gateway timeout on the reference example.

Comment: I'm talking about the left image, which you can see 9 objects orange.
This right image result after I ran the code, and when I introduced ncomp then have 11 registered objects.

Anyway, I'm working with OpenCV-2.4.9
visual studio 2012
Windows 7 64 bit

Comment: Why you need watershed? If you found contours, you can count them.

Comment: Hey, I did not understand your answer.
What is Watershed?

I want the counter will count 9 objects and not 11 objects
How do i do this?

Comment: Watershed is a technique used to do counting of objects when they slightly overlap.  If your objects never overlap each other, you don't need it.

Comment: Okay, so what do I need to change the code to get the right result of 9 objects?

Comment: I would love to enroll the revised code to get 9 objects.

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm count objects which labeled by watershed algorithm.The example which you gave there are 5 objects and 5 watershed label so it works fine.But you see your image has 9 objesct but 11 watershed labels. You should count the object before apply watershed.Actually, you don't need to apply watershed because your image is so clear to segment and count objects.You only turn image to binary from color image. After that find and count the contours.
The code is below.If you don't want to apply dilation you can get the number of objects with contours_eroded.size().This will give you number after erosion.If you don't want to apply any morphologic process you can apply findcontour function to binary image after that you can get size of its contours.

```
int main () {   
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
Rect bounding_rect;
Mat dst,bin;

Mat src = imread("example.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR); // reads image from file


cvtColor(src,dst,CV_BGR2GRAY);  // converts image from rgb(src) to gray level (dst) 
threshold(dst,bin,40,255,THRESH_BINARY); // Tresholds image with level = 40 from gray level(dst) to binary (bin)
findContours(bin,contours, hierarchy,CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE ); // finds contours on bin image

Scalar color( 255,255,255 );
for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ ) // iterate through each contour. 
  {
   if((contourArea(contours[i],false))>100){ // if counter area >100 pixel draw it on ero which is new image variable
    drawContours( bin, contours, i , color, CV_FILLED, 8, hierarchy ); //Draw contours on itself as filled
                                            }
   }

 findContours( bin, contours, hierarchy,CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE );

 for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ ) // iterate through each contour. 
  {
      bounding_rect=boundingRect(contours[i]); //Bound and Draw rectangle each object which detected at the end on src(original image)
      rectangle(src, bounding_rect,  Scalar(0,255,0),3, 8,0);  
   }
   namedWindow("Binary",CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
   imshow("Binary",src);
   cout<<contours.size();
   waitKey(0);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I did not know what to change the code. Could you please write down the code that would get the result of 9 objects?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help
I copied the code you wrote down, and I get lots of errors
What is the reason?
I work with:
visual studio 2012 c ++ console application

ScreenShot
http://imgur.com/QUHeBw4

Comment: write 'using namespace cv;
using namespace std;'
between include lines and int main () line
Also you should arrange in your own way. For example, I wrote for image name "example.jpg" do you have it ? I think no you should change it.

Comment: Hi, I ran the code you brought me, and I get the result 2
That is instead of 9, I get 2
It is not true
http://imgur.com/3ywi3UH

Comment: We learnt the process is true,so it doesn't matter.It is basic problem.You have to decrease contourArea. I gave it 1000. You can choose it less number such as 200 300 or decrease the threshold value 45. Or basically you can change last findcontours function as this;   findContours( bin, contours_dilated, hierarchy_dilated,CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE );
but in this case you have to delete between threshold(dst,bin,40,255,THRESH_BINARY); and  findContours( dilated_image, contours_dilated, hierarchy_dilated,CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE );

Comment: Sorry, but I did not understand you.
Could you please edit your comment and write the complete code?
So I would get the result of nine important to me to get a result nine, so I can test it on other images

Comment: Hi,
Sorry to make you crazy, but now I've checked and it does not work well in all cases.

You can see in the picture have 27 screen objects.
The code registers the result of 26 objects.
But there are two nearby objects, which identifies one object.
And there's another two points that it identifies as objects.

If you do not mind, I'd love to help another code.

its the result from the code:
http://imgur.com/2iMsMmE

its the real pic:
http://imgur.com/G9Uky3I

Comment: I think you don't have almost any information about image processing.Perhaps, this issue may be your homework or project. I gave you very basic working code. The first working code which detect 2 object instead of 9 is completely true for this basic issue.You have to learn what are thresholding, erosion and dilation. If you learn only a little bit information about it, you can arrange that code to work correctly on your images.You only have to make a change on parameters of thresholding,erosion and dilation operation.

Comment: It is not right to give you directly completely arranged code.You have to learn something.