# OpenCV Java count objects in photo

Tags: java, android, opencv

I have a small image and a large image and i want to use OpenCV to count how often the large image contains the small image (irrespective of rotation and size).

Example:

[image]

I don't want to use SURF or SIFT as they are nonfree modules. Maybe alternatives are BRISK or FREAK.

(Not like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34478402/opencv-how-to-count-objects-in-photo) post, because I want to count specific objects)

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

```
    for (int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
            int pixel = bmpOriginal.getPixel(x, y);
            if (pixel != Color.BLACK) {
                No_of_Objects = No_of_Objects + 1;
                Index = ((y - 1) * width + x);
                Connected[Index] = jumlahCrab;
                while (Index < 0) {
                    pixel = Color.BLACK;
                    Neighbors[x][y] = jumlahCrab;
                    Connected[Index] = jumlahCrab;
                }
                jumlahCrab++;
            }
        }
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(jumlahCrab), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, including an [explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/305455) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!